# SQL Trigger to verify account, if not verified dont process stored procedure/transactions

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to create a trigger or function to check a user against the database and if not verfied, the following stored procedure is not ran. I would like this option for verification check before stored procedure is ran

A function or trigger something along these lines

```
DECLARE @strtoken varchar(30)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid from users where token = @strtoken)
BEGIN
--stop any further transactions
END
```

Sorry, yes I meant to trigger the event of checking the token against the user table before any further processing of the stored procedure. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm using cookies and cookies can be changed. So I encrypted the token with MD5, 3DES and salted it. Right now I'm wrapping the stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @strtoken varchar(30)
DECLARE @userid bigint

IF EXISTS (SELECT userid from users where token = @strtoken AND userid=@userid)
BEGIN
--run stored procedure here WHERE userid = @userid
END
```

Of course, the user has to log in to use the web app, but I don't want anyone fiddling with the token. So I figured there was a way to check against the db with the token and if not verified, stop any further processing of the stored procedure without wrapping the entire stored procedure like I'm doing now

Comment: Why is the permissions system inadequate for the task?

Comment: In a trigger (`AFTER INSERT` ?) you could just simply roll back the running transaction to undo any inserts, if your criteria is not satisfied

Comment: I'm with @Damien_The_Unbeliever, this should be handled with permissions.

Comment: just verify (whatever you mean by that) user in trigger before procedure call. Where is problem exactly?

Comment: @Jānis And how would he fire a trigger prior to stored proc execution?

Comment: ooo, by "trigger" you mean not table trigger but some event that is triggered before procedure call.. Well.. you can wrap procedure in another procedure, that does verification. And there must be good reason why you do this verification otherwise than through standard user permissions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot use Triggers for this because Triggers do not fire in response to Read-type events (Execute or Select).  Nor should you because, in general, triggers are not an appropriate device for implementing security.

If you want to implement your security token idea on SQL Server(*) there are several general ways to go about it:

1. Alter your Stored Procedures:  Add an additional parameter to your stored procedures, then have your stored procedures themselves check this.  This is the recommended method.
2. Wrap your Stored Procedures: If you do not want to alter all of your stored procedures, you could instead do as one of the commenters suggests and write wrappers for all of your stored procedures.  The wrapper has the token as an additional parameter, which it first checks and then calls the actual procedure.  You use SQL-object security to prevent the actual procedures from being executed by anything other than the wrapper procedures.  This approach is not usually recommended because of the extra work and its higher maintenance.  However, this can be alleviated through automation if your database's security, schema and procedure design is structured correctly for it (this is how I do it, though not for this purpose).
3. A variant of #2 (above) would be to have a single Wrapper Procedure that calls all of the other procedures.  This would require that the first two parameters were the token and the actual procedure name and the rest would be the actual parameters shifted over two places.  The Universal Wrapper would then check the token and if valid, then call the actual procedure.  This is actually surprisingly easy to do (and does not require dynamic SQL either), however, it does also require properly designed security schemas to enable closing other security holes.  This approach is not usually recommended because of it's even higher dependence on properly designed security and schema structures and because auditors do not generally understand it and it makes them nervous.

(* - and this may well be something that is better addressed at the web/app server level, since that seems to be where the weakness is.)

Comment: I went with suggestion #2. It wasnt that much different from what I already had. As for the web app I already addressed security and sql injection. I check security client side, server side and on the database. This question was for added protection. Nothing like redundant security and data type verification at every level of the web app

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use SQL Servers built-in security and want to do it in a trigger then you need to use something like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER <your_trigger_name>
FOR INSERT
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT userid from users where token = inserted.strtoken)
BEGIN
    -- Stop any further transactions
    RAISERROR ('Place your error message here', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN  
END
```